# IFFE vs. function that returns a function

Tags: javascript

Consider the following:

```
var x = (function(){
    var _private = 'start';
    var _x = function(text){
        if(text){
            _private = text;
        }
        else{
            return _private;
        }
    }
    return _x;
})();

console.log(x()); //start
x('end');
console.log(x()); //end

var y = function(){
    var _private = 'start';
    var _y = function(text){
        if(text){
            _private = text;
        }
        else{
            return _private;
        }
    }
    return _y;
}
console.log(y()); //toString of function
y();//invoked function, should return _y?
y('end')
console.log(y()); //toString of function
```

I need some clarity as to why the `y` function does not behave the same as the `x` function after it has been invoked.  Why does the `y` function behave differently, and what overarching concept about IFFEs am I not getting?

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xmmddcgn/

Answer (score 4):

In the first example:

```
var x = (function(){
    var _private = 'start';
    var _x = function(text){
        if(text){
            _private = text;
        }
        else{
            return _private;
        }
    }
    return _x;
})();
```

`var x` is the **inner** `function` since the **outer** `function` was invoked.

In the second example `var y` is the outer `function` after you invoke it like this:

```
var y = function () {
    var _private = 'start';
    var _y = function (text) {
        if (text) {
             _private = text;
        } else {
             return _private;
        }
    }
        return _y;
 }

y(); // nothing happens and nobody keep _y's ref.
var p = y(); //p is _y

console.log(p()); //start
p('end')
console.log(p()); //end
```

Then `p` will be exactly the `var x` above.

Comment: Ah, this makes sense now.  I did not think about needing to assign y() to a variable that would then do what I wanted.  +1